# Woocommerce, variations, custom field and WP All Import plugin

Tags: woocommerce, wpallimport

I am trying to add a custom field for all my product variations and show this on the single product page.
I am using "[WooCommerce: Add/display Product or Variation custom field everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55773540/woocommerce-add-display-product-or-variation-custom-field-everywhere/55774613#55774613)" answer code and it does everything I need.

But the custom field is not visible anywhere in WP All Import plugin. Adding data manually to each variation works.

Also wondering if I am overcomplicating this a bit?

All help would be greatly appreciated.